# how to test if Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) I implemented works?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, algorithms, machine-learning

I have implemented Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) in C by referring various sources. Now, I would like to test the system with a simple configuration. How can I do that? I work on a speech recognition system and I get good results with the help of LDA (I use it for dimensionality reduction. I reduce vectors with dimension of approx. 90 to dimension of 18 using LDA). But I don't know how to quantify performance of my LDA.

Comment: by testing if it clusters the learning data correctly, then the test datas too, and if the function to be minimized is minimized, if its gradient is 0, ...

Comment: @reuns thanks for your comment. Did you mean to say, 
step 1. Compare the scatter matrix for learning data with and without lda
step 2. Compare the scatter matrix for test data with and without lda
Step 3: I did not understand what is meant by 'gradient is 0'?

Comment: yes you can calculate the intra class covariance matrices before and after LDA, or just look at the first eigenvector as a classifier, etc.. in fact my best advices would be to compare for the same datas your C program with a 3 lines matlab program to test if your eigenvectors extraction is correct, and if everything is ok. the matlab code for LDA is so simple and it's easy to plot the datas.. and for the gradient = 0 : your eigenvectors are the solution to a minimization problem (min intra class variance / inter class variance) look at wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Multiclass_LDA

Comment: @reuns thank you very much. But how can we compare a 90*90 intra class covariance matrix of original data with 18*18 intra class covariance matrix of data with reduced dimension?

Comment: by looking at the trace or the sum of the first diagonal elements !!! and don't forget to divide by the trace of the inter-class matrix (just the correlation matrix of the centroids), for normalization. really you should have fun with matlab, plot datas, PCA, LDA, plot your eigenvectors, etc. to understand what you are doing. Matlab has been created for  matrices/signal/data processing like you are doing.

Comment: @reuns Thank you once again. As per your suggestion, I will use MATLAB for evaluation. Still, I would like to know more about the trace(sum of diagonal elements). What is it's significance? Is the trace of 90*90 matrix and 18*18 matrix comparable? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Eigenvalue_relationships  the trace of the correlation matrix $=$ the sum of eigenvalues   being the overall variance (mean value to the centroids)

Comment: @reuns So that means, i have to calculate the trace of correlation matrix for each class (18*18) and then sum them across all classes and compare it with the same parameter for the data before LDA(90*90). The value should be high for the data after LDA. Am I right?